# $f(x, y)=(x^2-2y^2)e^{-x^2-y^2}$ is bounded

Tags: analysis, multivariable-calculus

I am trying to prove that the function

$$f(x, y)=(x^2-2y^2)e^{-x^2-y^2}$$

has an absolute maximum and minimum on $\mathbb{R}^2$.

I've found the local maximum / minimum ($\frac{1}{e}$ and $\frac{-2}{e}$) but am not sure how to show that they're also the global max/min.

Comment: Sorry but out of curiosity I'm asking as I am new to calculus did you find  the maxima and minima by implicit differentiation.

Comment: Consider writing this in polar coordinates as $ \ (x^2 \ + \ y^2) \ e^{-(x^2 + y^2)} \ - \ 3 y^2 \ e^{-(x^2 + y^2)} \ $ $ \ = \ r^2  \ e^{-r^2} \ - \ 3 r^2 \ (\sin \theta )^2 \ e^{-r^2} \ $ .  Is each term bounded? How do the terms behave far from the origin?

Comment: Once you've identified all the local extrema, the only thing left to consider is the behaviour at infinity, which is a bit more complicated than the $1$ variable case.  Nevertheless, it is relatively simple to bound $f$ above by $x^2 e^{-x^2-y^2}$ and below by $-2y^2 e^{-x^2-y^2}$, and then show that both of those tend to $0$ as $(x,y)$ grows unbounded.

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{d(x^2-2y^2)e^{(-x^2-y^2)}}{dx}=2x(1-x^2+2y^2)e^{(-x^2-y^2)}=0 $$so $$x=0 , x^2-2y^2=1  $$ 
$$x^2-2y^2=1$$ $$ \frac{1}{e^{(1-3y^2)}}<\frac{1}{e} $$
$$x=0$$
$$-2y^2e^{-y^2}=\frac{-2y^2}{e^{y^2}}>\frac{-2}{e}$$
since:$$(\frac{y^2}{e^{y^2}})^{'}=0$$ gives$$y=0.y=1,y=-1$$